# Why does GA4 CSV import status say 'unknown'?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to create a **user-scoped custom dimension in my GA4 property**. The dimension is related to the users' `Client-ID` and needs to be populated with an external CSV file. After having created the data source and made the mapping, **GA4 data import status says 'unknown'**. Do you know where the issue come from and how to fix it? Thanks for your help.

What I tried:

- Change the name of the columns in the CSV file
- Import the data using `User-ID`
- Import a CSV file directly extracted from BigQuery